# Expected class name before { error

Tags: c++, inheritance, arduino

I am trying to get to grips with inheritance in C++ before trying to implement something in a larger file.  I realise this question has been asked before but I've scoured literally everything I could find on this - nothing pointed me towards a fix.  So hopefully a kind SO member can help me.

I writing a library for Arduino just to be clear.  Here is my code:

**CtrlBrd.h**

```
#ifndef CtrlBrd_h
#define CtrlBrd_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class CtrlBrdClass
{
    public:
        CtrlBrdClass();

};

extern CtrlBrdClass CtrlBrd;

#endif
```

**CtrlBrd.cpp**

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "CtrlBrd.h"

CtrlBrdClass::CtrlBrdClass() {
}

int CtrlBrdClass::test()
{
    return 79;
}

CtrlBrdClass CtrlBrd;
```

**CtrlBrdEx.h**

```
#ifndef CtrlBrdEx_h
#define CtrlBrdEx_h

#include <CtrlBrd.h>

class CtrlBrdEx : public CtrlBrdClass {   // <----- Getting the error here!!

public:
    CtrlBrdEx();
    int test2();

};

extern CtrlBrdEx CtrlBrd;

#endif
```

**CtrlBrdEx.cpp**

```
#include "CtrlBrdEx.h"

int CtrlBrdEx::test2() {

    return CtrlBrd.test() +1; 

}

CtrlBrdEx CtrlBrd;
```

**Error:**

> error: expected class-name before '{' token

Comment: Did you post the entire error? Was there not a "header not found" sort of error before it? Those are important...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only solution is to include both files at the top of your main .ino code file.  The Arduino compiler doesn't seem to like including libraries from within libraries...

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
#include <CtrlBrd.h>
```

with

```
#include "CtrlBrd.h"
```

The exact sequence of locations searched by the compiler is implementation dependent in both cases (§16.2 [cpp.include]), but both [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html) and [VC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (and every other compiler if I had to guess) will search the current directory for the quoted form, but not necessarily for the other.

Comment: `extern CtrlBrdClass CtrlBrd;`, `CtrlBrdEx CtrlBrd;`, `CtrlBrdClass CtrlBrd;`, `extern CtrlBrdEx CtrlBrd;` could be annoying too, or am I wrong?

Comment: @ShinTakezou Depends on what you mean by *annoying*. There's nothing syntactically wrong them.

Comment: CtrlBrd declared as different thing... by annoying I mean it won't compile.

Comment: Yup, I caught the same thing. It may also be advisable to set the .h, the .cpp, and the class name to the same thing on CtrlBrd/CtrlBrdClass.

Comment: @ShinTakezou Sorry, didn't notice that two of those were named the same (in my defense, those abbreviated names are hard to read :-))! Yep, definitely a problem.

Comment: Doing this I now get " error: CtrlBrd.h: No such file or directory" as well as the previous error

Comment: also re: JasonMc92 I have used this odd naming as I am planning on extending a class which uses these same discrepencies

Comment: @HenryIng-Simmons Is the file really named *CtrlBrd.h* and is it in the same directory as *CtrlBrdEx.h*?

Comment: It is named CtrlBrd.h and no it is not in the same directory.  Does it have to be?

Comment: @HenryIng-Simmons Not necessarily, but you'll need to do one of two things to fix that. 1. Change the directive to `#include "CtrlBrd.h"` to `#include "path/to/CtrlBrd.h"`. Path can be absolute or relative to the location of *CtrlBrdEx.h*. 2. Leave the directive as is, instead pass the location of *CtrlBrdEx.h* to the compiler, for gcc `-Ipath/to/dir` and for vc++ `/I path/to/dir`

Comment: Please note this is for an Arduino application.  I am not using either of those compilers.  All these files are in the standard Arduino library location - hence why I was using <>

Comment: @HenryIng-Simmons So all 4 are files shipped with whatever Arduino dev kit you're using? You'll need to figure out what include path locations are being passed to the compiler. Since it can find *Arduino.h* it obviously knows where that file is. Once you figure out the include path you may have to then `#include` a relative path to *CtrlBrd.h*. It's hard to say without knowing the development environment and directory structure. And a Google search for Arduino and these filenames doesn't show anything (except this question). Are you adding your own files to the Arduino library?

Comment: I tried changing the include to "../CtrlBrd/CtrlBrd.h"
I now get "undefined reference to `CtrlBrdClass::CtrlBrdClass()'"

Comment: @HenryIng-Simmons That's progress :) Now make sure *CtrlBrd.cpp* is being compiled and you're linking all the object files together. Sorry to be vague, but I know nothing about your dev environment.

Comment: Interesting thing is if I put the CtrlBrdEx files in the CtrlBrd folder it all compiles fine and works.  But that's not what I'm looking for

Comment: @HenryIng-Simmons The only suggestion I have to offer is to figure out the command line arguments being passed to the compiler. Make sure all cpp files are being compiled and the object files created from them being linked together.